# Retrieving multiple Rows from database using javascript and display in an html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am trying to display the database values in  a html table using javascript but i am getting only the last value in the database table

```
function productValues() {
  if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){
    var responseJson= JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
    var length=responseJson.a1.length;
    document.getElementById("nid").value="";
    document.getElementById("pid").value="";
    document.getElementById("cid").value="";
    document.getElementById("name").value="";
    document.getElementById("price").value="";
    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
      var a=responseJson.a1[i];
      var b=responseJson.a2[i];
      var c=responseJson.a3[i];
      var d=responseJson.a4[i];
      var e=responseJson.a5[i];
      document.getElementById("nid").value=a;
      document.getElementById("pid").value=b;
      document.getElementById("cid").value=c;
      document.getElementById("name").value=d;
      document.getElementById("price").value=e;
    }
  }
}
```

//response

```
ProductSearch prod=new ProductSearch();
            prod.setA1(a1);
            prod.setA2(a2);
            prod.setA3(a3);
            prod.setA4(a4);
            prod.setA5(a5);

            String responseJson = new Gson().toJson(prod);
```

//html code

```
</head>
<form id="form1"  method="post" action="ProductNameSearchF">



                            <table  align="center">   
                                <tr>
                                    <td><font color="#006400"><b> Select Item:</b></font>
                                        <input type="text" name="searchname"  id="user" onclick="clearFields()"/>
<input type="button" id="submit" style=" color:#280000 ;font-size: medium;" value="Edit" onclick="getDetails();" />

<tr>

<br/></td></tr>

<div id="welcometext" align="center">
</div>
                            </table>

<TABLE cellpadding="8"  id ="table" border="1" align="center" style="background-color: #EEEEEE;">


<TR bgcolor="#66CCFF"><font color="#fff">
<TD color="#0080FF" width="0.1%" ><B>Id</B></TD>
<TD color="#0080FF" width="0.5%"><B>ProductType_Id</B></TD>
<TD width="0.1%"><B>Cuisine_Id</B></TD></font>
<TD width="0.5%"><B>Name</B></TD></font>
<TD width="0.5%"><B>Price</B></TD></font>
</TR>


<TR>
  <TD><input type="text"  name="id" id="nid"  style="background-color:transparent; color:blue; " readonly   ></TD>
<TD><input type="text"  name="productid" id="pid"  style="background-color:transparent; color:red; " ></TD>

<TD><b><input type="text"  name="cuisineid" id="cid" style="background-color:transparent; color:red; "   ></b></TD>
<TD><b><input type="text"  name="name" id="name" style="background-color:transparent; color:red; "></b></TD>
<TD><b><input type="text"  name="price" id="price" style="background-color:transparent; color:red;" ></b></TD></input>
</TR>




</font>
<font size="+3" color="red"></b>



</font>

<TR>

</tr>
</TABLE>

<table align="center">
    <tr>
     <td colspan="">  <a href="SearchFirstNameClear.jsp" style="text-color: #ffffcc;"><img src="clear.jpg" width="50" height="30" ></img></a> <button type="submit"  name="someName" value="someValue"><img src="redsubmit.png" width="70" height="30" ></button>  </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</table>



</form>
```

Here is my html code , i am  adding only the essntial code of the html page

Comment: Could you post the format of your responseJSON?

Comment: ProductSearch prod=new ProductSearch();
            prod.setA1(a1);
            prod.setA2(a2);
            prod.setA3(a3);
            prod.setA4(a4);
            prod.setA5(a5);
                    
            String responseJson = new Gson().toJson(prod);

Comment: Could you edit the original post to include a sample JSON object?

Comment: @user3825041 your setting the values to your ids inside of for loop, which will resets yours values. thats why your getting only last row values in your html page, could you include your html table?

Answer (score 2):

@user3825041:  In Html elements id a are unique in nature. I mean if we you repeatedly set same ids with different values, at the end you will have single value(i.e is the last one) updated. Due to which you are getting only last value.
Please try to change ids with each row update.

Or else you can use html table plugins like bootstrap table  which are easy and responsive to use. You just need to provide data(JSON/XML format) to these plugins.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

Answer (score 0):

You can generate table dynamically from javascript, to achieve it your (servlet) response should be like:

```
ArrayList<ProductSearch> al = new ArrayList<ProductSearch>();

... databse code ...

while(rs.next()) {
    ProductSearch prod=new ProductSearch();
    prod.setA1(a1);
    prod.setA2(a2);
    prod.setA3(a3);
    prod.setA4(a4);
    prod.setA5(a5);

    al.add(prod);
}
...
String responseJson = new Gson().toJson(al);
response.getWriter().println(responseJson);
```

And your html should be like:

```
<input type="button" value="Show Results" onclick="showTable()" />
<div id="dvTable"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showTable() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {  
                var responseJson = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
                var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
                table.border = "1";

                var row = table.insertRow(-1);

                var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
                headerCell.innerHTML = "nid";
                row.appendChild(headerCell);
                var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
                headerCell.innerHTML = "pid";
                row.appendChild(headerCell);
                var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
                headerCell.innerHTML = "cid";
                row.appendChild(headerCell);
                var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
                headerCell.innerHTML = "name";
                row.appendChild(headerCell);
                var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
                headerCell.innerHTML = "price";
                row.appendChild(headerCell);

                for (var i = 0; i < responseJson.length; i++) {
                    row = table.insertRow(-1); //creates new row
                    row.id = "row1"; // if you want to set id of row
                    var cell = row.insertCell(-1); // creates new column
                    cell.innerHTML = responseJson[i].a1; // put data in column
                    cell.id = "column1"; // if you want to set id of column
                    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                    cell.innerHTML = responseJson[i].a2;
                    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                    cell.innerHTML = responseJson[i].a3;
                    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                    cell.innerHTML = responseJson[i].a4;
                    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                    cell.innerHTML = responseJson[i].a5;
                }

                var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
                dvTable.innerHTML = "";
                dvTable.appendChild(table);
            }     
    }
</script>
```